# Ember observer / action syntax differences

Tags: ember.js, action, observers

I've read the documentation about the actions hash, but in every example I can find, people leave off the `action:` when observers are used.

like this one:

https://www.airpair.com/ember.js/posts/top-mistakes-ember-rails#6-properties-and-observes

They favor the action name direction under the extend definition just like how properties are defined, and an anonymous function is defined wtihin that property.

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    expand: function() {
      this.controller.set('isExpanded', true);
    }.observes('aProperty')
  }
});
```

vs

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  expand: function() {
    this.controller.set('isExpanded', true);
  }.observes('aProperty)
});
```

My question is what are the differences between these two ways?

Does it not bubble up if you don't use `actions:`?

If you don't use `actions:`, does it not bubble up to routes?

And most importantly, what does this mean for using observers?

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ActionHandler.html#property_actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions and observers are two entirely different things.

Actions handle actions invoked from templates via `{{action}}`, and actions invoked from JavaScript via `send`. Yes, they must be in an `actions` hash. Otherwise, they will not be found, much less bubbled.

Observers are just observers, and you can put them anywhere you want to observe something.

In your example, you given an action with an `observes`. What is the use case for that? What would you be trying to accomplish? It would seem to be **both** an action and an observer, which is a pattern I have never seen before and which doesn't seem too useful.

Comment: Thank you. What you say makes sense, but I'm having trouble integrating that with my understanding of the syntax. I updated my OP with code examples. Can you clarify further with those examples?

Comment: As far as terminology goes, would we call `expand:` in this case an observer? I was under the impression that something directly under the `extend(` was either a property or an action. I guess not. What's the generic term for the identifier before the `:`? A hash key? Or do we only refer to things in light of their context (e.g. property, observer, action)?

Comment: Syntactically, the thing before the colon is a property name or a key. Semantically, the `a: b` syntax directly in the object defines a property or method or computed property or observer; in the actions hash, it' defines an action. `expand` is not an observer (or shouldn't be); it's an action.

Comment: Then a defined action directly in the component/controller/route definition is called an 'action', and so is something defined within the `actions:`. Doesn't it get ambiguous when you try to specify one or the other?

Comment: Don't really get your question. Are you referring to the distinction between the "action" named `expand` and its implementation?

Comment: When I have something directly under the extend(, it's called a property. When I have action:, then something defined under it, its called an action. But what I I have it directly under the extend(, just like a property, but instead of only having a value there, I do an anonymous function?  Would this be called an action as well, or something else?

Comment: The anonymous function would be an "instance method" that could be called on an instance of the class. No, it would not be called an action.

Comment: So "the instance method has an observer attached to it" would be correct?

Comment: No, an observer would best be called an observer (mainly). You could think of it as an instance method which is mainly designed to be called magically at certain times, it could in theory be called manually, although that is not a common pattern.